# What is recommended Return air Grill location in a Basement?

Tags: hvac

I have to install a cold return air register in my basement ( of 8' ceiling). right now I have two options.

In the picture, I have shown two options A & B. which is better in term of return cold air from all open spaces (marked by red circle) more efficiently and what size of return grill do I need.

[image]

Comment: Instinctively, I would say B because it faces more area and less air has to 'turn a corner'.  For size I would say it should be the same size as the Main trunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct route (A) would allow for the air to be “pushed” in easily,. The one drawback would be possible noise from the fan.

The indirect route (B) would allow for deflection of the noise but create added Static Pressure on the fan which would increase noise little bit.

I would prefer B option as it cover most of large spaces without 90 degree turn. Use metal elbo than flex duct.

Add a ½” of duct liner in the return duct ( for metal case) to keep noise low.

Hope this help!

Comment: "Use metal elbow than flex duct"? This sounds like an answer from one of your own questions, but it applies to the supply. For the return it's more like a short 16x25in rectangular duct (or whatever the size of the return opening in the furnace)

Comment: I think using rectangular is less likely a DYI work as there is less flexibility in it, I agree rectangular is always a best option for return. But if PAN goes with B option, Won't it be too hard for him to make elbo ?. Also, Isn't 16X25 a over kill grill. Because in winter, if its more pulling from basement than up stair. it leads to high positive pressure on up stair which could make up stair more uncomfortable which we don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you pick it considering these factors:

- a central location relative to the output registers, as in a bedroom hallway
- where it is cold, as in a hallway or entry area with exterior doors
- close to the furnace to minimize ducting
- where it would not hinder you to place furniture (couch, shelving, boxes), so again in a hallway or breezeway
- where the furnace noise traveling through the return duct wouldn't bother you, so not in or near a home theatre
- not near the washroom or kitchen to avoid odorous intake

In your case I think the furniture placement is what really distinguishes A from B, and so it depends how you intend to use the furnished space.

Comment: Looks like more than one would be needed to me but this list works also.

Comment: @P2000, What if there is NO furniture near the option A and B.

Comment: @PAN then it doesn't matter. In a free open space (no furniture around A or B), the flow is the same. Pick whatever is easiest to give you access to build it. One minor consideration is whether you want to be able to reach *straight* into the furnace from the register, if the filter is jammed, a bird is stuck etc... then A (based on how I understand your excellent sketch) is easier.